# python virtualenv and Mac OS Monterey upgrade

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

after the upgrade to Monterey virtualenvwrapper doesn't behave. I've tried uninstalling it and re-installing it, deleting the old workspaces.

when I launch the mkvirtualenv this happens:

```
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /venvdir/venvname/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /venvdir/venvname/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /venvdir/venvname/bin/python3.7 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7' (should be 'my-project-dir/')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

whatever version of Python it's trying to use, from Cellar, is not working?

in my ~/.bash_profile there is:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/someworkspace
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

why is the python version is taken from "Cellar" rather than from VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON.

Another interesting this is that if I just run

```
python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

But I thought Monterey was using 3.8.9?

Does anyone know what has changed? Thanks T.

EDIT: small update, I've rewritten the question since I had another problem which was solved by restarting. The python version problem still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my file ~/.zprofile and changed the export:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3.7
```

restarted the terminal and I was able to create the virtualenvs again.

Comment: thanks, if you like to add to your answer this: the OS upgrade doesn't create the .zprofile or .zshrc files which are where to put the variables! So I created the .zshrc file, added my exports there (copied from the bash file), started a terminal, forced reinstall of pip and it worked!